# Multiple spark streams in spark application - logging per stream

Tags: apache-spark, logging, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark application which runs multiple structured streams. (Spark 2.3.2)

The problem is, that they all log to the same file.

Is there a way to set log file per spark stream?

Comment: structured or legacy?

Comment: structured streaming